# Dynamic Memory Allocation and using Classes

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am attempting to implement a GradeManager class that internally uses an array of DataVector objects that were created dynamically using the new operator, to record the homework grades for a set of students.

I am struggling to make the constructor/destructor.

Description for the constructor: "This is the only constructor of the class, and it specifies the number of students nStudents and number of homeworks nHWs for the class.  You should use these to dynamically set the array sizes."

Any thoughts you have to offer will greatly help!  This is what I have so far.  Thank you so much!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
//DO NOT INCLUDE ANYTHING ELSE!!
using namespace std;

typedef double DataType;//Alias for double type
typedef unsigned int UIntType;//Alias for unsigned int type

class DataVector
{
private:
    DataType *m_data;           //Pointer to dynamically allocated memory that holds all items
    UIntType m_size;            //Size of the m_data array

public:

    DataVector()
    {
        m_data = new DataType[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            m_data[i]=0;
        }

        m_size = 10;

    }

    DataVector(UIntType initSize, DataType initValue)

    {
        int arraySize = initSize;
        m_data = new DataType[arraySize];

        for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
            m_data[i] = initValue;
        }
        m_size = initSize;
    }

    ~DataVector()
    {
        delete [] m_data;
        m_data = NULL;
    }

    UIntType GetSize()
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    void Reserve(UIntType newSize)

    {
        int arraySize = newSize;

        DataType *new_data;
        new_data = new DataType[arraySize];

        for(int i = 0; i < m_size; i++){
            new_data[i] = m_data[i];}

        m_data = new_data;
        m_size = newSize;
    }

};

class GradeManager
{
private:
    DataVector *m_student;//m_student[0], m_student[1], etc correspond to sID 0, 1, etc respectively
    UIntType m_nStudents;//Number of students

public:
    GradeManager(UIntType nStudents, UIntType nHWs)
    {
        m_student = new DataVector[nStudents];

        m_student->Reserve(nHWs);

        m_nStudents = nStudents;

    }

    ~GradeManager()
    {

        int numOfStudents = m_nStudents;

        for(int i = 0; i < numOfStudents; i++)
            delete [] m_student;                   

        m_student = NULL;
    }

};
```

Comment: First thought : use `std::vector<>`

Comment: avoid `new` as much as you can(use only if you really have to),
as @quantdev suggested use `std::vector`.

Comment: So you're not allowed to include anything else, yet you use `NULL`, which isn't guaranteed to be in any of the existing headers.

Comment: Does the comment `//DO NOT INCLUDE ANYTHING ELSE!!` mean that it's homework and that you're now allowed to use the standard containters ?

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

1. Like stated in the comment by quantdev, use std::vector<> in the DataVector class - much simpler than using an array, though you cannot limit its size directly (as is done nearly-automatically with an array).
2. It seems you may have a memory leak and possible segmentation fault in DataVector::Reserve(). You allocate the new memory for new_data, copy the data from m_data into new_data (which brings to mind a thought; what happens if m_size is greater than newSize? IMO, a memory access error, but I'm not sure), then re-point m_data to new_data, without releasing the data stored in m_data in previous calls (say, in the constructor). This will lead to a memory leak.
3. Also, I'm not entirely sure the method DataVector::Reserve() reserves any space, if that's
   what it was meant to do.

Also, the constructor/destructor - in my opinion, at least - for GradeManager look fine, with most of the problems located actually in the DataVector class.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are not allowed to use the standard containers such as std::vector<> or std::array<> which could facilitate the job.

Your DataVector constructor and destructor are consistent:  you create a new dynamic array and your delete the dynamic array.

However inbetween, there is the function `Reserve()` that you call in GradeMaster constructor. 
Its `for` loop can go out of bounds, because the new size can be bigger or smaller than the old one.   You have to check that i remains in bound of both source and target:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_size && i<arraySize; i++){   //  check on source and target bounds !!!
```

Also you create memory leak by not releasing the old objects that you do not need anymore.  You have to insert this line after the end of your loop:

```
delete[] m_data; //  insert this to avoid memory leaks
```

A last point is int the GradeMaster destructor.  As you delete the whole array with `delete[]` you MUST NOT loop and try to delete the array several times !  Deleting the array, will delete all its elements.  Just remove the for line.